# Demonstration with complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

How can I show that $$\overline{e^{i\theta}}=e^{-i\theta}$$

I know that if z is a complex number so

$$\overline{e^z}=e^\bar{z}$$

But i don't understand how to show this result.

Comment: Just by $\overline{i\theta}=-i\theta$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$e^{i\theta}:=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\implies\overline{e^{i\theta}}=\cos\theta-i\sin\theta=\cos(-\theta)+i\sin(-\theta)=:e^{-i\theta}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the power series expansion of $\exp$. It has only real coefficients, so conjugating only affects the variable $z$.

Once you have the second equation you get the first because $\overline i=-i$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you already know that $\overline{e^z}=e^{\overline{z}}$, this is quite straightforward.

Simply take $z=i\theta$. Since $i$ is the imaginary number and $\theta$ has a real value, the complex conjugate of $z$ is simply: $\overline{z}=-i\theta$.

Therefore:
$$\overline{e^{i\theta}}=e^{\overline{i\theta}}=e^{-i\theta}$$